PostgreSQL pg_dump Fails: Password Authentication Error with Special Characters in Password
I am trying to execute a pg_dump command from PostgreSQL using a stored procedure. My setup uses EXECUTE format to dynamically construct the command. Here is the relevant code:
    'COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM ''script -c "PGPASSWORD=%s pg_dump -h %s -p %s -U %s -Z6 -Fc -v -d %s -t %s -f %s%s.sql" %s%s_log.txt''',
    ppassword, phost, pport, pusername, pdbname, atablename, pdumppath, atablename, plogdumppath, atablename
);

It works correctly with user and password 'postgres'.
But, when the ppassword value contains special characters like @ddG$fG#2@91 and I execute this, I get the following error:
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user_name"
connection to server at "ip_address", port xxxx failed: 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user_name"

I've confirmed the following:
The username, host, port, database name, and table name are all correct and have same rights as 'postgres' user.
The password works correctly when used manually in the PGPASSWORD environment variable or when logging in using psql.
It seems like the issue is with the special characters in the password.
Postgresql Version : PostgreSQL 16.4 (Ubuntu 16.4-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit
How can I correctly pass such a password to the pg_dump command in this scenario?

Probably an encoding problem. Windows, right?

You have too many layers of quoting there for me hazard a guess at how much of what needs quoting or escaping how many times... or what shell injections  you are vulnerable to.

@LaurenzAlbe, yes. Windows environment.

Starting pg_dump using, with the goal to set 1 environment variable for that process ( PGPASSWORD=%s pg_dump....) is not supported under Windows.

I think you can use the answer give here: How to pass in password to pg_dump?

NOTE: Location, and name, of the file .pgpass is different under Windows, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

@Luuk the issue is on passing special characters like @, #, $. I think those require some special escape sequences as I am passing this value as a string. I want to pass the value as it is, which is causing those errors. I went through the link and I am nowhere close to the correct answer.
My new course of action is to create new users with same privelegs and  create password using @, # and $ seperately

Please post a [mre] for this stored procedure, because I do not have time to create one myself.   Also tell us where your database is, is it local on your Windows, or remote a network device, or .....

yes. it is the environment of the database server that this stored procedure is running on that is most relevant to the answer (select version(); will tell you that)

@Jasen I have updated that in the question

Please post a [mre] for this stored procedure.  It is very hard to see what you are actually doing because of the many ' before, and in, the COPY statement. I do not want to guess something when trying to help you....
